# why this onclick function is not defined?

Tags: javascript, jsp

**layerAuthManage.jsp**

```
<input type="button" value="일괄선택"  onclick="chk_all()">
```

**spatialInfoGuide.js**

```
function chk_all(){
    $('[name=chk]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

**error message:**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: chk_all is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick (layerAuthManage.do:123)

Comment: No way to know based on the code you've shown. Maybe the JS file isn't included correctly, or the function is inside another function, or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you did not add jquery, thats why showing this error.

you can use below solution, i think it will help. if still error then share your code to see.

```
<html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="일괄선택"  onclick="chk_all()">
        <script>
            function chk_all(){
                $('[name=chk]').prop('checked', true);
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```